# PrimeNG p-autocomplete suggestion box doesn't overlap the background text properly

Tags: javascript, css, angular, primeng

I've used the p-autocomplete of PrimeNG and it seems to be working fine except that the suggestion box shows the option but the background text is also visible which makes the clarity of the options very poor.

I tried setting the baseZIndex and autoZIndex but nothing worked. Can you please help me as what could be wrong with it.

This is the attached screenshot for reference. If you look at the two dummy options - marker, marvel both are overlaping the label of second field.

Please suggest.

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="company1">My First Company</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
      <p-autoComplete inputStyleClass="form-control rounded-0" [size]="100" 
        formControlName="firstCompany" [suggestions]="companies" 
        (completeMethod)="searchCompany($event)"
        field="name" [minLength]="1" forceSelection="true" field="name"></p-autoComplete>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create this problem in Stackbliz.

Comment: I'll see if I can add one.

Answer (score 2):

try to put this attribute in p-autocomplete:

`appendTo="body"`

Comment: I tried this one also but nothing changed.

Comment: Thank you that worked for me but instead of body, Iused the ID of the input.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to resolve it. The problem was missing primeng theme.css import in style.css. I added the below line in my style.css file:

@import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap4-light-blue/theme.css'

Thanks for your time.